# expressing constraints in relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

I need to express this constrain in relational algebra:

I have some table with one column with all possible values: ALL_VAL

and table with some values from ALL_VAL that not mach some rule: NOT_FIT_VAL

and  I can calculate  FIT_VAL = ALL_VAL - NOT_FIT_VAL

what i need is a constraint: in FIT_VAL there minimum one item.

I am using  not equal sign with empty group:

ALL_VAL,

NOT_FIT_VAL

FIT_VAL = ALL_VAL - NOT_FIT_VAL

FIT_VAL <> {empty}

but I am not sure that <>(not equal) is allowed at all in relational algebra
there is not a single book or article that shows example or saying that I can use it.

I would like some clarification about it, and the correct expression.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the expression "FIT_VAL <> {empty}" is not a relational expression (it does not produce a relation, but a truth value instead), therefore it is a bit problematic to consider such expressions as being "valid relational algebra expressions".

But that is strictly speaking, and I don't know how much slack your textbook cuts its readers/users in that area.  Under the "strictly speaking" approach, it is even outright impossible to use relational algebra to define constraints, because the definition of a constraint must produce a boolean result (does the database satisfy it or not) almost by definition.  That is probably the reason why it is so highly exceptional to see relational algebra being used to express/define database constraints !

Another approach for defining database constraints using relational algebra, is to define a relational expression that plays the role of "faults expression" and then implicitly, tacitly assume that the rule is that the result of evaluating this expression must at all times be empty.  But that's (AFAIK) an entirely private approach of mine, and I'd be surprised if you had also found it in a textbook.