# Is there a way to refer to the current date in relational algebra, like CURDATE in MySQL?

Tags: constraints, relational-database, relational-algebra

I want to write a constraint using relational algebra that the current date has to be less than the expiry date in a specific relation. I'm aware this is easy in SQL, but not sure how to do it in relational algebra.

Comment: A constraint is a true statement or part of one. A relational algebra query returns a relation. What do you mean, "write a constraint using relational algebra"? PS There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. What DBMS/system are you using, what context are you doing this in? How are functions accessible to queries? [mre] PS [What is the equivalent, in Relational Algebra, of a SQL Table Relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48905581/3404097)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [expressing constraints in relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28457182/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Use `TODAY`, which would read naturally in a diagram/algebra.